# How to apply MySQL cryptography functions in Jooq custom Converter?

Tags: java, jooq, jooq-codegen

I'm trying to achieve below using Jooq library,

- Encrypt and decrypt specified column using org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDSL methods
- This must be a jooq global configuration, so that whenever a new query method return fetch/insert/update the record encryption/decryption should be automatically taken care.
- Secret key for encryption/decryption will be value from the another column in the same table
- I'm trying to avoid Spring framework here.

Currently I'm trying to do this using `org.jooq.Converter` and `org.jooq.meta.jaxb.ForcedType` But

- Not able to access `org.jooq.RecordContext` in the CustomConverter class to get the secret key
- Also I'm not able to make this generic configuration

Links I'm referring to:

- https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/util/mysql/MySQLDSL.html
- https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/util/mysql/MySQLDSL.html
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.18/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-converter/
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/data-type-conversion/

Update:
In short this is what I'm trying to achieve through Jooq:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTCRYPT(
Id mediumint AUTO_INCREMENT,
Secret int NOT NULL,
encrypteddata BLOB,
PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

INSERT INTO TESTCRYPT(Secret,encrypteddata) VALUE ('1234',AES_ENCRYPT('my-data','1234'));

SELECT Secret ,AES_DECRYPT(encrypteddata,Secret) from TESTCRYPT t ;
```

Comment: Do you have to use MySQL's encryption/decryption functions, or can you work with client side encryption/decryption as well? And what's the rationale for this decision?

Comment: To not deviate from existing conventions in the system, I've to use the MySQL's encryption/decryption methods.

Comment: I couldn't actually figure out the way to access current ```org.jooq.RecordContext``` inside ```Converter```

Comment: Yeah, because that's already possible today. There's a pending feature request for the server side implementation, but it's not ready yet for jOOQ 3.18.

Comment: @LukasEder
I've updated my question, do you see any other possibility to achieve my goal in Jooq v.3.17.8 ?
Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't find the feature request, so I created a new one, just in case: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14913

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An out of the box feature

As of jOOQ 3.18, there isn't an out of the box feature for this sort of computation. I've created a feature request, as this isn't the first time someone was looking for it:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14913

### Custom implementation on the server side

If you must encrypt / decrypt on the server side using SQL expressions, perhaps you can get away with the new experimental [query object model](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/) [traversal](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/model-api-traversal/) and [replacement](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/model-api/model-api-replacement/) features.

The idea is that you:

- Specify which columns or types are supposed to be encrypted (either in a configuration or using a custom data type)
- Then transform all SQL queries to always

  - Replace `Field<MyType>` by `Field<byte[]>` using encryption in contexts where a bind variable is written
  - Replace generated SQL for all `Field<MyType>` to decryption in contexts where a projection is made
  - Leave other expressions untouched

### Custom implementation on the client side

All of this seems much easier to achieve with a simple `Converter`, if you can encrypt / decrypt on the client instead of the server.

Comment: Even in case of client side encrypt/decrypt, how to access the secret key from the same table in ```Converter``` ? Could you please point me to that?

Comment: @introvertkernel: A converter cannot access other columns. But that doesn't sound like a good idea anyway, why encrypt stuff and store the key along with it?

Comment: I agree it doesn't add any substantial value to data security. But however in this case it is used to prevent insider's from viewing the plain text data.

Comment: Is there any other way where atleast these two methods can be used to achieve the same? ```org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDSL.aesEncrypt``` and ```org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDSL.aesDecrypt```.    



The problem, how do I customise/alter a Field with the help of the other Field from the same table.

@Lukas

Comment: @introvertkernel: I think my answer contains all the info you need? If you have any specific questions regarding the replacement feature, please ask a new question.