# How to convert a Field in jooq custom converter using other fields in the same Record?

Tags: java, jooq, jooq-codegen

- Need to apply custom field conversion logic in `org.jooq.Converter` implementation.
- The custom conversion is a encrypt / decrypt the field
- The key for encryption / decryption will be available in the same `org.jooq.RecordContext`  i.e: In the same table another column will have key.

If below is not possible what are the other ways to achieve this?

```
public class CustomFieldConverter implements Converter<String, String> {

    
    @Override
    public String from(String databaseObject) {

        // do MySQLDSL.aesDecrypt(databaseObject, Field('keyColumn')
        // How to access keyColumn field here?
        // 
    }

    @Override
    public String to(String userObject) {
        // do MySQLDSL.aesEncrypt(databaseObject, Field('keyColumn')
        // How to access keyColumn field here?
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> fromType() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> toType() {
        return String.class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably misunderstood [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75939555/521799). All you do in a `Converter` is:

- 100% client based, so you cannot apply any SQL functions in there
- 100% single column expression based, so you cannot access any other column values

There's no way to achieve what you want to do with a `Converter`. [My previous suggestion of using a `Converter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75939555/521799) was meant to hint at doing all the encryption / decryption completely in the client, not partially in the client. This means you have to have that key available in memory to do any encryption / decryption using Java API, not using MySQL API.